# UITextField added to SubView when refreshing

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield

I'm adding a TextField to a View displaying a timestamp whenever a user does an event:

```
    let now = NSDate()

    let textString = NSLocalizedString("LAST_UPDATE", comment: "Last Update: ") + self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(now)
    self.refreshTimeText = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: (self.tableView.frame.size.width / 2) - 100.00, y: 125, width: 200.00, height: 10.00));
    self.refreshTimeText.text = textString
    self.refreshTimeText.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 10)
    self.refreshTimeText.textAlignment = .Center

    self.refreshTimeView.addSubview(self.refreshTimeText)
```

Initially my issue was the previous TextField timestamp was showing under the new TextField, I corrected this by adding `self.refreshTimeText.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`.

Am I doing this the right way? If a user decides to spam the refresh button (100 times), will I have 100 TextField on top of each other?

I have a feeling that I'm just applying a coat of paint to mask imperfection instead of doing the proper work.

Comment: Sounds more like a UX question rather than a technical question...

Comment: I don't think the user cares, I'm asking to ensure I'm doing it the proper way and not taxing the resource by having 100 TextField on top of each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this will keep on adding a text field each time. 
You can check that using textview.subviews.count and see for yourself that the count is increasing

Rather than adding a text field each time you should add one text field at the beginning and just set the string value to the date each time the user clicks the button

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should be using a UILabel. UITextFields are only needed if the user needs to change the text.

You should add the label to your xib file and set it to hidden (either tick hidden in the xib file, or in viewDidLoad(). Hook it up to an IBOutlet

Then, in the click event set hidden=false and update the text

Or you could avoid setting hidden=true if you just leave the label text empty